# Which React Lifecycle Methods for controlling state of buttons (enabled/disabled)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `SearchBar` Component like so:

```
class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      page: 1,
      prevButton: false,
      nextButton: true,
    };
```

And buttons like so:

```
<div>
      <button
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        onClick={this.handlePrev}
        disabled={!this.state.prevButton}
      >
        Prev Page
      </button>
      <span className="SearchBar-page-numbers">{this.state.page}</span>
      <button
        className="btn btn-secondary"
        onClick={this.handleNext}
        disabled={!this.state.nextButton}
      >
        Next Page
      </button>
    </div>
```

Now I want to add code that *for every component update* will check which page on the user is.

-

So if the user is on page number one (`this.state.page === 1`) `this.state.prevButton` should be always false, but for every other page `this.state.prevButton` should be always true.

`this.state.nextButton` should be false only when `this.state.page === 10`

I need navigation between page 1 to 10 only.

-

Which ***React Lifecycle Methods*** would be sufficient for that functionality?

---

I tried something like that but it is no good, it is unclear, messy and doesn't work...

```
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

    if (this.props !== prevProps) {

      if (this.state.page === 1) {
        this.setState({ prevButton: false });
      }

      if (this.state.page !== 1) {
        this.setState({ prevButton: true });
      }

    }

  }
```

---

**UPDATE:**

---

### ***If you see better way of doing this, please share you thoughts!***

Full code of that component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import {
  wakeUpHerokuServerFromSleep,
  fetchRecipesAndPage,
  loadRecipes,
  showClickedInfo,
  addLocalStorageToFavoritesList,
} from '../../actions/';
import './style.css';

import ButtonSearch from '../../components/ButtonSearch';

class SearchBar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      term: '',
      page: 1,
      prevButton: false,
      nextButton: true,
    };

    this.handlePrev = this.handlePrev.bind(this);
    this.handleNext = this.handleNext.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.wakeUpHerokuServerFromSleep();
    const localStorageData = JSON.parse(
      localStorage.getItem('lastSavedFavourites')
    );
    if (localStorageData) {
      this.props.addLocalStorageToFavoritesList(localStorageData);
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (this.props !== prevProps) {
      this.setState({ term: this.props.showClickedInfoFromStore });
      this.checker(this.props);
    }

    const { page } = this.state;
    if (prevState.page !== page) {
      this.setState({ prevButton: page !== 1 });
    }
  }

  // If some ingredient was manually selected
  // go to page 1 of that ingredient
  checker(properties) {
    if (properties.manualSelectionFromStore) {
      this.setState({ page: 1 });
    }
  }

  // If input was changed go to page 1
  handleInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({ page: 1 });
    this.setState({ term: event.target.value });
  }

  // After submit, go to page 1 and fetch data
  handleSubmit(event) {
    this.setState({ page: 1 });
    if (this.state.term === '') {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.showClickedInfo('');
    } else {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.props.fetchRecipesAndPage(this.state.term, 1);
      this.props.showClickedInfo(this.state.term);
    }
  }

  handlePrev() {
    let newPage = this.state.page - 1;
    if (newPage <= 0) {
      newPage = 1;
    }
    this.setState({ page: newPage });
    this.props.loadRecipes(newPage);
  }

  handleNext() {
    let newPage = this.state.page + 1;
    if (newPage >= 10) {
      newPage = 10;
    }
    this.setState({ page: newPage });
    this.props.loadRecipes(newPage);
  }

  buttonsView() {
    // Show navigation buttons (prev, next):
    // If there is an error coming from server
    // OR
    // If current search isn't null AND app has found some data and successfully fetched it
    if (
      this.props.error ||
      (this.props.currentSearchFromStore !== null &&
        this.props.checkIfSomeDataWasFound)
    ) {
      return (
        <div>
          <button
            className="btn btn-secondary"
            onClick={this.handlePrev}
            disabled={!this.state.prevButton}
          >
            Prev Page
          </button>
          <span className="SearchBar-page-numbers">{this.state.page}</span>
          <button
            className="btn btn-secondary"
            onClick={this.handleNext}
            disabled={!this.state.nextButton}
          >
            Next Page
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    }
    // Esle return just <div />
    return <div />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="SearchBar-input-group">
          <input
            className="form-control"
            placeholder={this.props.showClickedInfoFromStore}
            value={this.state.term}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
          <ButtonSearch className="btn btn-secondary submit">
            Search
          </ButtonSearch>
        </form>
        <div className="SearchBar-pagination-buttonsView">
          {this.buttonsView()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    error: state.error,
    currentSearchFromStore: state.currentSearchTerm,
    checkIfSomeDataWasFound: state.checkRecipesData,
    showClickedInfoFromStore: state.showClickedInfo,
    manualSelectionFromStore: state.manualSelection,
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      wakeUpHerokuServerFromSleep,
      fetchRecipesAndPage,
      loadRecipes,
      showClickedInfo,
      addLocalStorageToFavoritesList,
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchBar);
```

Comment: Why don’t you set state prevButton with page at the same time? If you use componentDidUpdate, it renders twice.

Comment: Perhaps a full example, showing how `state.page` is updated would be helpful. I'd recommend to not store `prevButton` and `nextButton` in the component state, and create two helper functions instead `isPrevButtonEnabled(props, state)` and `isNextButtonEnabled(props, state)` to use directly in the `render` method.

Comment: @godsenal could you add your solution without rendering twice? I'm not sure I understand what you mean...

Comment: Some parts of your state can simply be derived from other information you already have. I don't see a reason to have `prevButton` or `nextButton` as boolean in your state as you can simply check for the page number in your render. Keep your state as small as possible.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, thank you @trixn!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternately, you could just disable the buttons based on `page` as follows:

```
const { page } = this.state;

<div>
  <button
    className="btn btn-secondary"
    onClick={this.handlePrev}
    disabled={page === 1}
  >
    Prev Page
  </button>
  <span className="SearchBar-page-numbers">{this.state.page}</span>
  <button
    className="btn btn-secondary"
    onClick={this.handleNext}
    disabled={page === x}
  >
    Next Page
  </button>
</div>
```

I'm not sure how you are disabling the next button, but subsitute `x` above with the number of pages.

Comment: Yea, now I understand! Better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your 'which lifecycle method' question, I would suggest using componentWillReceiveProps if you're checking whether something should re-render based on props changes.  You'd compare this.props to nextProps (pass in nextProps as the argument to componentWillReceiveProps) in that method, and perform an action based on that.

However, if you're just trying to determine whether to enable/disable buttons, you could use the following in the 'disabled' property of the buttons.

i.e. for 'previous' button

```
disabled={this.state.page === 1}
```

and for 'next' button

```
disabled={this.state.page === 10}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps()` is beginning to get deprecated starting in React 16.3 so it may be wise to consider alternate options

Comment: @Tony - thank you for pointing that out!  I haven't read through all the changes for 16.3 yet.  :)